# Executing all stored proceedures in one script

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

i am handing over a project to a another party which i have been doing for some time, in this  project i do some modifications to some of the existing table by adding coloumns, renaming coloumns etc.
When i was handling the project what i did was, putting the changes or the modifications inside a stored proceedure once it was run calling the function from the query browser.

stored proceedure

```
CREATE DEFINER=`my_db`@`10.%` PROCEDURE `alter_test_1`()
BEGIN
DECLARE v_finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE v_table VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT "";
DECLARE stmt VARCHAR(500) DEFAULT "";
DECLARE column_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM `information_schema`.`tables` WHERE table_schema = 'my_db' 
AND table_name LIKE 'tot_table_%';
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER 
FOR NOT FOUND SET v_finished = 1;
OPEN column_cursor;
alter_tables: LOOP
FETCH column_cursor INTO v_table;
IF v_finished = 1 THEN
LEAVE alter_tables;
END IF;
SET @prepstmt = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE my_db','.',v_table,' CHANGE OS platform VARCHAR(25);');
PREPARE stmt FROM @prepstmt; 
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END LOOP alter_tables;
CLOSE column_cursor;
END
```

afterwards i run

```
call alter_test_1();
```

in the query browser.

Now as im handing this over this two step excution is not professional therefore is there a way for me to do this by using another stored proceddure instead running a `call alter_test_1()` separately... what i mean is there a way to put this **call** or several **call** statements inside a stored proceedure and excecute all the **call** statements in one shot, once that particular stored proceedure is run.

Comment: done!!! :D any mysql experts

Comment: guys any stored proceedure experts

Answer (score 0):

Well... you call a stored procedure within another stored procedure... by calling it.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `do_things`()
BEGIN

  CALL `alter_test_1`();
  CALL `do_more_stuff`();

END
```

Executing `CALL do_things();` will first run your procedure, then one called "do_more_stuff" and then will return.  It will terminate at the first unhandled error thrown unless you catch the error with a `HANDLER`.

That seems like the answer to the question you asked.  I'm less clear about whether that was the question you intended to ask, because you talk about "2 step execution," and I don't see what the 2 steps are.

If you are asking how to *run* a stored procedure (step 2?) without *declaring* it first (step 1?), then, no, you can't...  it's a "stored" procedure, and has to be stored before it can be executed.